# Angular.js data-bind background images using media queries

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, media-queries

I have an Angular.js application with dynamically background images (should have data-binding for their URL). I also want to use css media queries in order to detect orientation/pixel density etc.

The only solution I found is using javascript to add URL to the background image, something like this:

```
myDiv.css({'background' : 'url('+ scope.objectData.poster +') no-repeat', 'background-size':'auto 100%'});
```

This way I have to pass all media queries logic to javascript, something like [this](http://paulhammant.com/2013/02/08/angular-instead-of-media-queries/). (My intention is to be able to serve different background image for each screen resolution / pixel density / orientation)

I am looking for a cleaner solution to use css media queries and still be able to data-bind my image sources.

tnx!

Yaniv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a starting point solving your problem.

You may use matchMedia: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
    $scope.poster = 'small.png';
} else {
    $scope.poster = 'big.png';
}
```

now you can use it in the html file:

```
<div class="moments-preview-image" 
    ng-style="{'background-image': 'url('+poster+ ')'}"> ... </div>
```

If your browser doesn't support this new API you may have a look on some interesting workarounds:

http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/

http://davidwalsh.name/device-state-detection-css-media-queries-javascript

Comment: The matchMedia solution works great for me (I'm developing for mobile devices). Tnx!

Comment: @Yaniv How about Windows Phone devices? [MDN says that IE Mobile isn't supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia#AutoCompatibilityTable)

Comment: Oh - might be... I'm only developing for iOS & Android devices. What about using a Polyfill? Did you look for one? (for example: https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/). Good luck!

Comment: Wow never know we can do this. I tried `ng-style="'background-image','url('+card.thumb+')'"` and failed however, don't know why. Perhaps it only supports `{'a':'b'}` syntax.

Comment: according to docs ng-style only supports an expression that evaluates to an object of `{'css property key' : css value}`.