# Any way to rearrange objects with css, javascript or any libs?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, responsive-design, media-queries

Right now I have a big headache called "APP Responsive" i handle the issue of wallpaper and the size of the images to use. Now my dilemma is this rearrange all the objects for the application look more neat as possible, and not "empty" spaces are or very "tight" objects appear

This will be resolved with [css media query](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) (as i did for backgrounds and screen size), but after investigating the different screen sizes on smartphones market got me with the following:

Exist an average of resolutions that you can see in this [chart](http://thedigitaldisciple.net/smartphone-screen-resolution-chart/)

Similarly can review an interesting list on wikipedia that leads you think that there are no resolutions on the graph and can be important.

Whereupon i wonder there is a way to rearrange other than having to write a lot of media querys wide screen combination.

And this is based on that the next: the vertical space between a between an object A and an object B in 1280Hx720W screen should not be the same as on a screen 1920Hx1080W (though both have the same pixel ratio 16:9) as that would make are empty spaces.  I  know exist hearings where there is no choice, but you can arrange objects to be pleasing to the eye.

I hope I explained and can count on your support to end my dilemma

NOTE: on the web the majority speak of adapting images with css media queries, but not rearrange objects

PS: Resources investigated

[Handleling image size on multiple device display on cordova-ionic-angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24276961/handleling-image-size-on-multiple-device-display-on-cordova-ionic-angular-app/24295986?noredirect=1#comment37581792_24295986)

[Angular.js data-bind background images using media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21000338/angular-js-data-bind-background-images-using-media-queries)

https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill

https://github.com/tinacious/angular-picturefill

http://bjango.com/articles/min-device-pixel-ratio/

https://gist.github.com/marcedwards/3446599

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices

Comment: One thing I did notice about that chart is that those resolutions do not account for device pixel ratio. For example my phone, HTC One (M7) has a device pixel ratio of 3. Even though it is 1920x1080, the browser reports a resolution of 640x360 (360x640 portrait), thus your media queries would affect those widths, rather than at 1920/1080

Comment: Thats right, I'm using the base resolution example iPhone 5s has 2x the resolution to use in media querie are 320Wx568H, but for the other device I have to get the pixel ratio then divide with the resolution report for the fabricant and then wrote the my media querie? That's crazy.